# Brown spots around my kittens nose and chin

Tags: cats

[image]

I'm wondering if these are bruises from playing with my other kitten or allergy as i saw a few other posts mention?

Comment: Did the behavior change in any way? Scratching the nose, being more active, less active, using the litter box... If there is no other change, it might be just coloration. NOTE: if you really suspect a medical case, then please go see a veterinarian. Internet people, no matter how well intended, cannot make a proper diagnosis.

Comment: @virolino we will be bringing her to a vet today thank you, she still is playful and acting good